# Custom control: How to override default properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, custom-controls

I've created a custom control similar to a button.
I want to override his default properties, but it works strangely.

UserControl Xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="project.MyButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="50">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse x:Name="structure" Fill="Black" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2"/>
        <Label x:Name="content" Content="&#xE081;" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl Code Behind (C#)

```
    /// <summary>A simple custom button.</summary>
    public partial class MyButton : UserControl
    {
        /// <summary>Background color.</summary>
        public new Brush Background { get => structure.Fill; set => structure.Fill = value; }

        /// <summary>Foreground color.</summary>
        public new Brush Foreground { get => content.Foreground; set => content.Foreground = value; }

        /// <summary>Stroke color.</summary>
        public Brush Stroke { get => structure.Stroke; set => structure.Stroke = value; }

        /// <summary>Stroke thickness.</summary>
        public double StrokeThickness { get => structure.StrokeThickness; set => structure.StrokeThickness = value; }

        /// <summary>Font family.</summary>
        public new FontFamily FontFamily { get => content.FontFamily; set => content.FontFamily = value; }

        /// <summary>Font weight.</summary>
        public new FontWeight FontWeight { get => content.FontWeight; set => content.FontWeight = value; }

        /// <summary>Font size.</summary>
        public new double FontSize { get => content.FontSize; set => content.FontSize = value; }

        /// <summary>Content.</summary>
        public new object Content { get => content.Content; set => content.Content = value; }


        /// <summary>Inizialize new <see cref="MyButton"/>.</summary>
        public MyButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Result

[image: Custom round button]

But, when I try to set the Background property it colors the background of the control, and not the ellipse, when I try to set the Content, it overrides the button, etc...

Example: `Background="Red"`

[image: Background Red]

Comment: Instead of hiding base class properties you should just use them, and bind the internal elements' properties to them, e.g. `<Ellipse Fill="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>`.

Comment: Works for all properties except than the Background.
It colors the entire control, other than the ellipse.
There is a way to color only the ellipse, by reusing this property?

Comment: You'd have to replace the UserControl's ControlTemplate by one that only contains a ContentPresenter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a `ControlTemplate` for the `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="project.MyButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="50">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse x:Name="structure" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                <Label x:Name="content" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

Using a `TemplateBinding` for a property of en element in the template, you can set this property of the `UserControl` to change the property of the element in the template:

```
<local:Button Background="Red" Content="&#xE081;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

UserControl has its `Backround` and `Content` properties, which are wrappers for DependencyProperties.

You are trying to shadow them using `new` keyword before property, but it fails. (set a breakpoint in setter: breakpoint is never hit)

When setting `Background="smth"` or `Content="smth"` from xaml, base properties are detected, and additionally WPF doesn't use wrapper properties, it uses `DependencyObject.SetValue()` directly. And setting base Content simply removes existing Grid with Ellipse.

Rename Background ->  CustomBackground, Content -> CustomContent and set them. Then MyButton will work.

Much better is to reuse base Content and Background though (bind them to Ellipse and Lable in MyButton xaml).